# How to handle batch processing with graph neural networks?

Tags: graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I have a network of 225 sensors. I have data at every 5 minutes for the month of October 2022. The total observations for a node are 288*31. The data is in 2 csv files sensor_data.csv,  and labels.csv
sensor_data.csv: it has 288*31 observations of data for every sensor. each row represent one month data of all all sensors. the total columns are 225. (one for each sensor)
labels.csv: it has a binary label corresponding to sensor data information. for normal data it is 0 and 1 otherwise. each row represent 1 month label information of all sensors at that timestamp.

adjacency: it is adjacency or connectivity matrix 225 x 225 defined in the code

The data is like the timeseries. the first column has the timestamp and at each timestamp data of all sensors is in next column. a small potion of data is given below

| Time | node1 | node2 | node3 | node4 | node5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2022 0:00 | 107.6 | 107.6 | 107.6 | 107.6 | 107.6 |
| 10/1/2022 0:05 | 105.1 | 105.1 | 105.1 | 105.1 | 105.1 |

The label data is on same format as given below

| Time | node1 | node2 | node3 | node4 | node5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2022 0:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10/1/2022 0:05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 10/1/2022 0:10 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 10/1/2022 0:15 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

The labels 1 are rare in the data and I am interested to predict these labels from the time series.

I have the following code but it is not working at all due to inconsistent dimension of input/output of layers.

when forward(self, input, adj) is called. I expect the size of support to be consistent with adj matrix. input is torch.Size([32, 225]) (batch_size x n_sensor). self.weight.shape is torch.Size([225, 64]). I got support shape torch.Size([32, 64]). So output = torch.bmm(adj, support) is invlaid and thus Runtime error.
output = torch.bmm(adj, support) # [batch_size, num_nodes, hidden_features] **RuntimeError**: batch1 must be a 3D tensor

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch.optim as optim

# Load data from CSV files
sensor_data = pd.read_csv('sensor_data.csv')
labels_data = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')


n_sensor = 225
for i in range(n_sensor - 3):
    adjacency_matrix [i][i + 1] = 1
    adjacency_matrix [i][i + 2] = 1
    adjacency_matrix [i][i + 3] = 1
    adjacency_matrix [i + 1][i] = 1

# Standardize the data
sensor_data_values = sensor_data.iloc[:, 1:].values
data_mean = np.mean(sensor_data_values)
data_std = np.std(sensor_data_values)
sensor_data_values = (sensor_data_values - data_mean) / data_std
adjacency_tensor = torch.tensor(adjacency_matrix, dtype=torch.float32)



def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
    super(GraphConvolution, self).__init__()
    self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(in_features, out_features))
    self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(out_features))
    self.reset_parameters()

def reset_parameters(self):
    nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight)
    nn.init.zeros_(self.bias)

def forward(self, input, adj):
    support = torch.matmul(input, self.weight)  
    
    output = torch.bmm(adj, support)  

    output += self.bias  
    return output




class GNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_nodes, hidden_features):
        super(GNN, self).__init__()
        self.gc1 = GraphConvolution(num_nodes, hidden_features)
        self.gc2 = GraphConvolution(hidden_features, num_nodes)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
    def forward(self, x, adj):
        x = self.gc1(x, adj)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.gc2(x, adj)
        return x

# Hyperparameters
epochs = 1
learning_rate = 0.01
hidden_features = 64

# Model, Loss and Optimizer
model = GNN(num_nodes = 225, hidden_features=hidden_features)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()  # As it's a binary classification
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Convert data to tensor
inputs = torch.tensor(sensor_data_values, dtype=torch.float32)
labels = torch.tensor(labels_data.iloc[:, 1:].values, dtype=torch.float32)

# Create data loaders
batch_size = 32
dataset = TensorDataset(inputs, labels)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = model.to(device)
adjacency_tensor = adjacency_tensor.to(device)
lossHist = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for batch_inputs, batch_labels in loader:
        batch_inputs, batch_labels = batch_inputs.to(device), batch_labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(batch_inputs, adjacency_tensor)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item() * batch_inputs.size(0)
    
    avg_loss = total_loss / len(dataset)
    lossHist.append(avg_loss)
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss: {avg_loss}")
```

The data is available at this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1COoQoQciFBVbjQGvX_2hY10Ysq82ZCvT?usp=sharing)

Comment: "not working correctly"  What do you get, what do you expect and how do they differ?

Comment: I am getting the following error. With batch processing the data, the weights and input shape is messing up somewhere. I tried to reshape but again in the next layer similar issue arises.

    output = torch.bmm(adj, support)  # [batch_size, num_nodes, hidden_features]

RuntimeError: batch1 must be a 3D tensor

Comment: " messing up somewhere"  is just as vague as "not working correctly"   What do you get, what do you expect and how do they differ?

Comment: when forward(self, input, adj) is called. I expect the size of support to be consistent with adj matrix. input is torch.Size([32, 225]) (batch_size x n_sensor). self.weight.shape is torch.Size([225, 64]). I got support shape torch.Size([32, 64]). So output = torch.bmm(adj, support) is invlaid and thus Runtime error.

Comment: I notice that you have added a report of a runtime error.  So "not working correctly" is incorrect - it is not working at all.  As for "messing up somewhere" you can find exactly where it is "messing up" by running under a debugger.  Please edit your question so that the problem is described accurately and show the result of running under a debugger.

Comment: Comments crossed.  You now have enough information to post a valid question.